# Two-dimensional random walk

Tags: probability, markov-chains, brownian-motion, martingales, random-walk

First, let's start with the problem in one dimension.

Let's have $R_1, R_2, R_3, ...$ be i.i.d., and $P(R_1 = 1) = P(R_1 = -1) = \frac{1}{2}$. The question would be:

"How many trajectories $(Y_n)$ there are, such that we start from $(0, 0)$, (where the first slot would be the time, and the second would be the position) and end at $(2n, 0)$, and between time $1$ and $2n$ it doesn't touch the $0$. We can see that all the path like that are $2$ times paths that go from $(1,1)$ to $(2n - 1, 1)$ , and that would we $\binom{2n - 2}{n - 1}$. All the paths that go from $(1, 1)$ to $(2n - 1, 1)$ that have a position $0$, would be $\binom{2n - 2}{n - 2}$, which can we found using reflection principle. So, for $\mathbb{N} =\{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ and $\tau = \text{inf}\{n \in \mathbb{N}: Y_0 = 0\}$, which would just be time before the first instance of our trajcetory going back to $0$, our probability of going to position $0$ at any given $\tau = 2n$ is equal to $P(\tau = 2n) = \dfrac{2(\binom{2n - 2}{n - 1} - \binom{2n - 2}{n - 2})}{2^{2n}}$.

Now, for the two dimensional problem, for $R_1, R_2, ...$ i.i.d. with $P(R_1 = 1) = P(R_1 = -1) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $S_1, S_2, ...$ i.i.d. with $P(S_1 = 1) = P(S_1 = -1) = \frac{1}{2}$, both independent of each other. What would be our $P(X_\tau = 2k)$?

(edit) Just to be clear, my question is "After $2n$ moves, what is the probability that we are back at the $X$ axis for the first time?". This is the extenstion of the $1d$ problem.

I got to the point where I knew it would be an infinite sum, but I just can't seem to crack this.

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If your walk is $(R_n, S_n)$, then your process is indeed a 2D random walk - but it's sort of a diagonal random walk since each step is taken in one of the four diagonal directions rather than the cardinal directions. This is fine, because you could just rotate the picture by 45 degrees and obtain an ordinary RW on $\mathbb Z^2$. However, if that is indeed what you're doing, and you only care about visiting the $x$-axis (and not the origin), then you should just ignore the first coordinate and observe that the problem is now identical to the 1D problem.

Comment: Please state precisely what is your question in 2 dimensions.

Comment: @YuvalPeres Edited the question to make it more precise

Comment: You question is still unclear to me ... like what is $X$ ? are $S,R$ independent ? If $X_n=(K_n,Y_n) = (\sum_{j=1,..,n} S_j,\sum_{i=1,..,n} R_i)$ such that $X_0=(0,0)$ and  $K,Y$ are independent . Then $P(X \text{ first return x-axis at time 2n }) = P(Y \text{ first return 0 at time 2n }) = P(\tau=2n)$ .

Comment: I'm just saying "$X$" as an axis when you are drawing the problem. And yes, $S$ and $R$ are independent of each other.  So you are saying that it's the exact same probability as for the $1d$ problem?

Comment: I think yes, because  joint probability of independent events factors

Comment: Incidentally, it seems more natural to me for the analogous 2D question to ask how many trajectories return to the origin for the first time after $k$ steps. Unfortunately, I don't think you'll get a nice Catalan-ish answer anymore...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fleshing my comment out into an answer: this is not an *extension* of the 1D problem; it is, in fact, precisely the same as the 1D problem.

You are considering a process $(R_n, S_n)$, where $R_n, S_n$ are both independent 1D random walks. This is a diagonal walk on the integer lattice $\mathbb Z^2$, because the parity of the two positions will always match. Note that the $x$-axis is reached if and only if $R_n = 0$, and that $S_n$ is irrelevant; hence, your question is equivalent to considering when $R_n$ reaches $0$ again for the first time, and you already have your answer.

I want to stress that your random walk on $\mathbb Z^2$ is not quite the traditional one; for instance, it is impossible to reach the state $(1, 0)$. In order to consider the traditional random walk, you can't allow $R_n, S_n$ to be independent of one another, since exactly one of them must move at any given step. The question of the first return to the $x$-axis in the traditional walk is not *quite* as simple as the solution I outlined above, in that case; instead, when restricting to $R_n$, you now have a **lazy** random walk (meaning a walk that steps left or right with probability $1/4$ and does nothing with probability $1/2$). You can indeed calculate the first return to $0$ of this lazy random walk, but it isn't the same calculation as the one you've already done.

Final note: you can turn your random walk into the traditional one by rotating it by $45^{\circ}$ and scaling it down by $\sqrt 2$. However, the line you originally called the $x$-axis also rotates and becomes a diagonal line when considering the problem in this way. In other words: your question is equivalent to the expected first return of the traditional random walk to the *diagonal set* $\{(x, x)\}$.